# How do I remove an asp.net identity user when constraints have been placed on the table?

Tags: c#, linq, constraints, asp.net-identity

In this `ActionResult` I am deleting users from my ASP.NET Users table.

```
public ActionResult Delete(string UserName)
{
    var thisUser =
    _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(UserName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
    _context.Users.Remove(thisUser);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

However when I try to delete a user I get the following error:

**The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.UserLogs_dbo.AspNetUsers_Customer_Id". The conflict occurred in database "MYDATABASE", table "dbo.UserLogs", column 'Customer_Id'.
The statement has been terminated.**

I know that the constraints are put there to prevent data corruption and this is fine, but how would I go about removing the constraints just enough for me to remove the user and then add them back after the user is removed?

Comment: `how would I go about removing the constraints just enough for me to remove the user and then add them back after the user is removed` If you dont need it then why have it in the first place? Remove foreign key constraint from the table. Its conflicting for a reason. `You need to remove the entry from other table before removing from users`. I understand you need it as a log? then why do you need a foreign key constraint?

Comment: @TheUknown using code-first the constraints are created automatically anytime I want to reference the `ApplicationUser` in another table. But I do not want to delete the user logs or the user orders. That is very bad for risk management and accountability

Comment: Using code-first you write the code and define the constraint - how can they be created automatically? in DB first, it would.

Comment: You can either get the row, then remove from db causing conflict and then delete from Users and add again OR just remove the constraint. I'm guessing you know that already. Whats your actual question here?

Comment: @TheUknown that was my question, seriously. I know I can delete the orders and the logs but I would rather not do that. I am using code fist, however still being rather new to MVC, i gave little to no attention to the migrations where I could have removed the constraints and updated the changes to the database. I guess I could remove the constraints, it will cause less of a hassle, I will get to keep my logs and orders when I want to simply delete the user

Comment: Yeah..You got it!

Comment: @TheUknown can I do that within the controller or in SSMS? Also, how will this affect the roles table or ASP.NET Identity Roles?

Comment: In SSMS. If you don't remove from the database now and refresh the entity model later, it'll be back again. So remove from the database I.e drop constraint and then update the entity model.. you can just right click and click update model from database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you are in trouble. But there are ways to fix it.

You don't want to mess with the foreign keys just to delete a user, yet constrains are there for a good reason. And you want to delete the user records.

Let's see the scenario - user registers, does something on your site that generate a few log records with user id referencing back to the user. Then user decides that he no longer likes your system and deletes his profile. If you remove FK constraint, then remove a record from Users table, then restore the constrain, you will get records in Logs table that contain UserId. But 2 months down the line you want to look up that user - you'll find that the ID does not point anywhere. That makes the logs pretty useless.

So your options are:

- Soft Delete - don't actually delete user records, but set a flag that they have been deleted and make sure that all the systems that access Users table know about this flag and ignore soft-deleted records.
- Denormalise user information into logs. Do not have a FK constraint into logs from Users, but keep in logs userId, username, possibly email. This way you'll still know what user done what, and you'll be able to trace actions of deleted users. And you won't need to mess about with FK when you trying to delete a user. This is what I'm doing in my systems, but I'm not logging into DB, but into other storage where FKs to SQL are impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily disable all constraints for the table to avoid the error, and then enable it back as below:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
--Run query here
ALTER TABLE <table_name> CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL
```

See [more info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175041.aspx)

Comment: This would work in SQL, however I am using asp.net MVC5 c# and linq

Comment: @Skullomania yet there is a SQL database underneath to store the data.